# pendingToken in response payload of signInWithIdp

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

What does the `pendingToken` parameter mean, in the response payload of a successful POST to `signInWithIdp` in the Firebase Authentication REST API ([Sign in with OAuth credential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/?authuser=0#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential) endpoint) ?

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key={{key}}' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  .....
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: identitytoolkit.googleapis.com' \
  -d '{
    "postBody": "id_token=eyJraWQiO....JWCJHHrxeg&providerId=apple.com",
    "requestUri": "https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler",
    "returnIdpCredential": true,
    "returnSecureToken": true
}'

{
  "federatedId": "apple.com/ABCDE.abcde1234567895ab21ab098234.1234",
  "providerId": "apple.com",
  "email": "user@privaterelay.appleid.com",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "localId": "12345678abcdef",
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...RiFQ",
  "refreshToken": "AEu4I...N0DuQ",
  "expiresIn": "3600",
  "oauthIdToken": "eyJraWQiOiJB...Hrxeg",
  "rawUserInfo": "{{...user info...}}",
  "isNewUser": true,
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyAssertionResponse",
  "pendingToken": "AMzJoSn....jNlcw"                    <-------
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**pendingToken** is a private property accidentally left in public header.

The team at Firebase are working to remove it, as they say

> "It's a field of no use case at all".

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/2676)